# Nuget files generated in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, nuget, xamarin.forms

I'm working in a Xamarin.Froms project using Visual Studio 2015. I already connected the project to use VSTS to host the code.

The application is working as expected. However, all of the sudden in the Team Explorer Tab under Excluded Changes I noticed a bunch of unchecked file:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Not sure why the files in the images were generated. The App still is running as expected. But, should I check in those files in VSTS? Or is it safe to remove all of them?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these files are .nupkg file (nuget package file) that stored in packages folder. These files is downloaded when you install packages and used to restore the packages for your solution. In other words, they are packages caches.

So if you could work with your project without check in to VSTS, the folder can be safely left out of the repository. But if these packages take a long time to download when restore them, I suggest you check them into VSTS, which can save a lot of time to download them from nuget feed.

There has other communities who has the similar issue, please refer to:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/301547/should-we-include-nuget-package-folder-in-version-control